# Stripe API checkoutSession creation with metadata fields is not consistent

Tags: stripe-payments, metadata

Using the Stripe API, I realized that the checkoutSession creation is not consistent.

To recall: you can create a checkoutSession on your Server and when successful, then you get the `payment` information on your Stripe Console.

And also to recall: there are two different `modes` that you can create your checkoutSession with: a) `mode = payment` or `mode = subscription`.

Now the problem:

- if I create a checkoutSession with `mode = 'payment'` then I find the `metadata` fields inside the `payment` Metadata. (i.e. clearly visible in the Console unter `Payments: Metadata`)
- if I create a checkoutSession with `mode = 'subscription'` then I do NOT find the `metadata` fields inside the `payment` Metadata. (but rather the metadata can be found under `Subscriptions` Console.

Question: How can I make sure that the Metadata of `Payments` Console also shows the Metadata (the ones given when the checkoutSession was created at the first place) ??

```
const checkoutSession: checkout_sessions = {
      id: checkoutSessionId,
      mode: 'subscription',
      customer: customerId,
      client_reference_id: referenceId,
      currency: currency,
      created: Date.now() / 1000,
      line_items: line_items,
      success_url: session.success_url,
      metadata: {
        checkoutSessionId: checkoutSessionId,
        // bunch of other metadata-properties
      },      
      billing_address_collection: 'auto',
};

const returnCheckoutSession = await customer.checkout_sessions.create(checkoutSession);
```

The above code clearly states `mode = 'subscription'` and also inlcudes metadata-properties. But the resulting Metadata fields of the succesful `payment` is `null` ?  How can I change that ?

(and I do not care if the metadata can be found under Subscriptions Panel. I am only interested in getting them inside the `Payments` Console's Metadata. i.e. the same location, they also end up with `mode = 'payment'`....

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Metadata in Stripe's API are **per API resource** and in almost all cases isn't automatically copied to other API resources. There are a few exceptions such as a Charge inheriting the metadata of its parent PaymentIntent at the time of its creation but that's rare.

The code you shared sets the `metadata` on the **Checkout Session** API Resource. It is expected that it wouldn't be copied to the resulting PaymentIntent or Charge or Subscription in the API. You mentioned you see it in the Console which I assumed meant the Dashboard but that's likely referring to Checkout itself.

Instead, what you should do is explicit force the metadata on the underlying object. For a payment you want to use the `payment_intent_data[metadata]` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-metadata) and for a subscription you want to use the `subscription_data[metadata]` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-subscription_data-metadata) instead.

It's also important to know that for subscription mode, it will set metadata on the **Subscription** API Resource. This won't magically be inherited by the Invoice or the PaymentIntent or the Charge. You'll have to write some code/logic to sync this yourself after each Invoice or PaymentIntent is created if that's what you want.

Comment: thank you for your detailed explanations. That's very consistent with what I observe.